# CodeIgniter URL rewrite not working

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to redirect url in CodeIgniter framework with **www.hostname.com/crm/some/url** to **www.hostname.com/index.php?/some/url**

I wrote following rule in my .htacess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^crm(.*)$ index.php?/$1     [L]
```

When i try this in browser, i get page not found 404 from codeIngnitor. But if add [R] flag in the redirect rules, it works proper and i could see the new url as expected after the change.

I tried apache rewrite log. Everything looks proper. I have no what URL the CodeIgniter frame sees after rewrite. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are doing this? The current URL is neat, the new one not so much..

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're not using the typical Codeigniter .htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can follow this, Do this code copy and paste in your .htaccess file. I think
>   it will help you.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|uploads|themes|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```